# How do I display German characters in flutter?

Tags: flutter

When I try to display words containing German characters, I get the following for überschreitung:
[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOvc7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Find your desired character and put it after \u like this :
For example:

The output for the "g\u00D6" will be gÖ

Take a look at the 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/charcode/charcode-library.html

To find your special codes